# Why "SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff" does not disable CapsLock completely in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

Why

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
```

does not disable CapsLock completely?

Answer (score 0):

There have been bug reports about `SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff`, saying that it doesn't work for all cases.

The bug report titled
[bug with setcapslockstate, alwaysoff](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/79752-bug-with-setcapslockstate-alwaysoff/)
has this explanation by a forum administrator:

> AutoHotkey uses a system-wide keyboard hook to suppress the keypress. In most cases this is sufficient, but there are some specialized APIs which will detect it anyway. If the other application uses one of these APIs, there's nothing that we can do about it. (In this case, remapping Capslock via the registry may be effective, since it changes the meaning of that physical key.)